# Managing memory usage when getting many screenshots in Java

Tags: java, memory, screenshot, bufferedimage, out-of-memory

I'm developing a software in Java which continuously takes screenshots of the desktop, stores it in a BufferedImage objectt then writes it to jpg files. At some point, the program causes a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space exception. Since I take a screenshot and save it as a file I don't need the previous BufferedImage objects in memory anymore so I can throw them away. Java doesn't seem to recognize these objects so they probably are still in memory. Is there a way to remove these in the JVM's memory so it doesn't run out? Continuously calling System.gc() probably won't help. Any ideas?

Here's the code for reference:

```
public BufferedImage getScreenShot() {

    BufferedImage screenImage = null;
    try {

        GraphicsEnvironment ge= GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        GraphicsDevice[] screens=ge.getScreenDevices();
        Rectangle allScreenBounds=new Rectangle();
        for(GraphicsDevice screen: screens)
        {
            Rectangle screenbounds = screen.getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds();
            allScreenBounds.width+=screenbounds.width;
            allScreenBounds.height=Math.max(allScreenBounds.height, screenbounds.height);
        }


        Robot robot = new Robot();
        screenImage = robot.createScreenCapture(allScreenBounds);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Screen.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return screenImage;
}
```

I then just have a loop that continuously calls the method to generate the BufferedImage object, resizes it, and writes it to a file like this:

```
while(true){
  FileImageOutputStream out = new FileImageOutputStream(f);
  writer.setOutput(out);
  IIOImage image = new IIOImage(ImageUtils.resize(getScreenShot(), width, height),null, null);
  writer.write(null, image, iwp);
  writer.dispose();
}
```

Comment: you could go pro and use the native java function. I havent used it yet but it lets you use c/c++ in your java code allowing for higher performance.

Comment: System.gc() doesn't guarantee GC at the time of call, so that option is not guaranteed. Post your code that may help in identifying any memory leaks.

Comment: did you invoke flush() on the buffered image?

Comment: @Scorpion no, I haven't. How does flush help in freeing up the memory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to remove the reference variables of earlier used BufferedImage objects. Then Garbage Collector will automatically release the memory occupied by them when needed.

As you are continuously taking screen shots, so I think you will be having some sort of looping thing and you will only be creating new variables but the earlier used variables will also be present in memory, as their reference still exists.

So try removing their reference variables. Then when memory will be almost filled then Java *Garbage Collector* will automatically come into play and will release your memory for you.

Comment: What do you mean by removing reference variables? Based on the code I just posted, since I'm calling the getScreenShot() method and pass it as a parameter to another method, I'm thinking all variables in the getScreenShot() method, as well as the BufferedImage object produced will be dereferenced ... is that enough to dereference it? Or are you referring to something else?

Comment: @Paul I think prolems is in your while loop section, you are creating IIOImage image objects in each iteration. So it will keep on adding new variables along with holding earlier used variables. Try using only one variable (declaring IIOImage outside the loop).

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, when the use of variable is completed, tell garbage collector that it is no more used. You can say that by referencing the object to null.

In your case after this line

```
writer.write(null, image, iwp);
```

try adding this line

```
image=null;
```

Comment: Whats ur default heapsize specified? I guess your max heap allows only one screenshot of data. With your current code, at a given point of time, you will have 2 screenshots data.